# Extract number from a string with some specific pattern front and back in php

Tags: php, regex

I know there are a lot of post out there, but I really cannot find any match.
I have a string
`"com/i598816441262.htm?sourceType=item&ttid=227200"`

I would like to extract the numbers after 'i' and '.', which is 598816441262 in the example, I can target the whole thing, "/i598816441262." but I just want the numbers, and don't wanna do it twice if I can do once.

Please, anyone give me some advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for lookarounds, which are zero-length assertions, something like this `(?<=\/i)\d+(?=\.)`

- `(?<=\/i)` means that there must be `/` before it.
- `\d+` means a bunch of numbers.
- `(?=\.)` means there must be a `.` after it.

So, a bunch of numbers with `/i` before them and `.` after them.

In PCRE, you can also use `\/i\K\d+(?=\.)`, `\K` keeps what's before it out of the match.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code. I'm showing you the step by step but you can do all of that in one line:

```
$string = 'com/i598816441262.htm?sourceType=item&ttid=227200';
$dot_pos = strpos($string, '.');
$string_before_dot = substr($string, 0, $dot_pos);
$only_numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string_before_dot);
echo $only_numbers;
```

Result:

```
598816441262
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex

```
$string = 'com/i598816441262.htm?sourceType=item&ttid=227200';

preg_match("/(?<=\/i)\d+(?=\.)/", $string, $match); 
echo $match[0];
```

With a bit of simple text fiddling

```
$string = 'com/i598816441262.htm?sourceType=item&ttid=227200';

$p1 = strpos($string, '/i')+2;
$p2 = strpos($string, '.htm')-5;

echo substr($string, $p1, $p2);
```